# Integrating $\int_{1}^{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{t}}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

I just started my calculus 3 class 2 years after taking my calculus 2 class and I'm having trouble remembering how to solve some integrals.  This one below is really confusing me as I couldn't find any specific integration techniques to apply to it.

Any hints?

$\displaystyle \int_{1}^{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{t}}dt$

Comment: Try to substitute $u=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{t}}$...

Answer (score 4):

Using $\displaystyle \int\sqrt{\frac{1+t}{t}}dt= \int\sqrt{\frac{1+t}{t}\times \frac{1+t}{1+t}}dt = \int\frac{1+t}{\sqrt{t(1+t)}}dt $

Now Put $\displaystyle t= u-\frac{1}{2}\;,$ Then $dt = du$.

So we get $$  = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-\frac{1}{4}}}du+\int\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-\frac{1}{4}}}du$$

For First Integral $\displaystyle u^2-\frac{1}{4}=v^2\;,$ Then $2udu=2vdv\Rightarrow udu = vdv$

So we get $\displaystyle\frac{du}{v} = \frac{dv}{u}=\frac{d(u+v)}{u+v}$ (Using Ratio and Porportion.)

so we get $$=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{v}+\int\frac{v}{v}dv$$

So we get $$=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d(u+v)}{(u+v)}+v = \ln|u+v|+v+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: How did $\sqrt{t(1+t)}$ in the denominator become $t\sqrt{1+t}$ in the next step?

Comment: Hamed I have edited my post.

Comment: This is still troubling! In last integrals all of the denominators are $\sqrt{u^2-1/4}$ not $u^2-1/4$. In fact if you fix this mistake then you haven't really done anything other than substituting $t=u-1/2$ in the original integral. This I don't think helps at all!